# fbDidLogin not called

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

So, I've been messing around with the Facebook iOS SDK for a bit and as of the latest version I can't get the fbDidLogin method to be called. The login process works fine, with Safari used on the simulator and the Facebook app being used when running it on a device. However, after logging in I get transferred back to my app (as I should be) but as the fbDidLogin method hasn't been called, nothing has changed. As far as my app is concerned I'm not logged in. 
The demo app that is bundled with the SDK works fine. So I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I have no idea how to check what. I triple-checked all the methods used in the demo app against my own and as far as I can see everything looks the same. Any thoughts or ideas on how to debug this? Or has anyone had similar problems?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you set your controller properly? Do you alloc init in the app delegate, set up a singleton? Not sure how to get the controller set up properly. I alloc my facebook class inside a custom class called facebookprep. That class is setup as the delegates for the facebook class. However, fbDidLogin doesn't get called. How did you initiate your facebook class?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I encountered the same issue just now. I solved it by adding the following code into my application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[controller facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

where controller is my `UIViewController` instance and facebook is my `Facebook` instance.

You also need to register your app to handle your fb application's URL scheme (do that in you Info.plist).

Comment: Yeah, I had done that, however I had missed actually setting my controller properly, when initiating it. Once I did that it worked.

Comment: @Glitch. What kind of mistake did you do initially? I also called this code and fbDidLogin is not called. I did not put it in app delegate but instead in another view controller which is the parent of the view controller which initializes and calls Facebook Request

Comment: Damn, right! Instead of "return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];" the "[controller facebook]" fixed my login problems!

Comment: how do I get my controller instance from inside the delegate?

Comment: @AndréCytryn You don't really need a controller instance. I just happened to have a property on a controller when I answered the question. You simply need to get an instance of the Facebook class and let it handle the URL.

Comment: @AndréCytryn To answer your actual question: You usually create a property on the delegate if you want to store a reference to a controller. For example: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *controller;`

Comment: @Jiri thanks for the help. I already managed that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930344/facebook-fbdidlogin-outside-appdelegate

Comment: This post is old, but thanks, I spent hours debugging a problem and this was the solution

Comment: very well answered. It helped me.

Comment: Bu what is the explanation behind the addition of Viewcontroller to the code

Comment: @rd4code as I have noted in a previous comment, when I originally answered this question, I copied the code from one of my projects and the fact that the facebook instance was a property on a view controller is not essential

Answer (score 6):

One common mistake could be to not implement the following callback method in your main app delegate, but elsewhere. Implement this method in your class derived from UIApplicationDelegate. This is the entry point that iOS calls after the context switch to bring your application back to foreground.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
     // obtain facebook instance ref
     [ facebook handleOpenURL: url ];
   }
```

If you have created FB application Id correctly and mapped the URL appropriately as defined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios then it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem, If facebook is the object of your first viewcontroller that is being loaded by ur appdelegate, then you can use viewcontroller property of appdelegate to refer facebook object e.g

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
     [ viewController.facebook handleOpenURL: url ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My cause for this was that I did not have the Facebook init in the ApDelegate using the correct delegate.  I had it pointing to self, when it should be using the view controller where the user actually performed the login.

From AppDelegate:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"111111111111111" andDelegate:homeViewController];
```

Comment: it can be pointed to self if you place it in the view controller where its called

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [ facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

should write on AppDelegate.m so that it will accessible for whole app.

please like it if it works

Answer (score 1):

Like Jiri said in the first comment You should implement these method in you app delegate

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [[loginScreen facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Where loginScreen is your view controller that you want to use for logging or making any thing else with Facebook , the point it is some place else than the App delegate.

Delete these method If you are using it

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently just encountered this as well.  My problem was that the app settings on facebook were configured in a way such that the app was not being authorized.  Hence, my fbDidNotLogin method was being called.  The solution was to go to

- `Facebook Developers` -> `Apps` ->`My App` -> `Edit Settings` ->`Basic`
- Make sure that under the section "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" the category "Native iOS App" was not enabled (green check mark).