# facebook fbDidLogin outside appdelegate

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, delegates

I have read many questions about the facebook login but until not I didnt succeed on solving my problem. I have made a few apps so far but I have never messed with the appDelegate before.

The thing is that I want to call the fbDidLogin method that is inside my class other than delegate.

Until now, fbDidLogin is being called in the appDelegate, but I want to be able to change the view and ask for user info after the login happens.

My code so far:
AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId) andDelegate:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

// This one is called correctly
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"[DELEGATE] Deu login!");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

My own class with the facebook login button:

```
- (void)loginFacebook {

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSLog(@"[LOGIN] Facebook session invalid");
        NSArray * permissions =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 @"email",
                                 @"user_birthday",
                                 nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];   
        [permissions release];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"[LOGIN] Facebook session valid");
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
    }
}
// I want this one to work so I can ask for user info at the end of it
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"[LOGIN][FB] Deu login!");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

I sorry if this is not clear, if you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can post a notification from the App Delegate like so:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBDidLoginCalled" object:nil];
}
```

And then in your other class:

```
- (void)loginFacebook {

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fbDidLoginNotificationFired) name:@"FBDidLoginCalled" object:nil]
        NSLog(@"[LOGIN] Facebook session invalid");
        NSArray * permissions =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             @"email",
                             @"user_birthday",
                             nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];   
        [permissions release];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"[LOGIN] Facebook session valid");
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
    }
}
// I want this one to work so I can ask for user info at the end of it
- (void)fbDidLoginNotificationFired {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"FBDidLoginCalled" object:nil];

    NSLog(@"[LOGIN][FB] Deu login!");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed it by adding this code on the -loginFacebook:

```
myIphoneAppDelegate * MyAppDelegate = (myIphoneAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MyAppDelegate.loginController = self;
```

Then on my appDelegate I created a property of my login controller and then calling the controllers -fbDidLogin:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self.loginController fbDidLogin];
}
```