# - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result not called

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why does this method never called? who can help me to review my code, i am a green hand.

here is my *.h file

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <FBSessionDelegate,FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate> {

    Facebook *facebook;
    IBOutlet UITextField *_txt;
    NSString *facebookUserID;
```

I want to get the faceboo user ID,So i called the API '[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];'

```
- (void) fbDidLogin
{
    NSLog(@"[LOGIN] Used did login");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    // User has logged in to Facebook, now get their userId from Facebook 
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];     
}
```

I know below method will get the user ID,but it never called.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{
    NSLog(@"Inside didLoad");     
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // When we ask for user infor this will happen.
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        //NSDictionary *hash = result;         
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [result objectForKey:@"name"]);

        self.facebookUserID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"ID: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the openURL or handleOpenURL (the latter is prior to ios 4.2). It needs to be implemented in your app delegate, not your view controller.

See [fbDidLogin not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called/4250836#4250836). openURL will result in fbDidLogin getting called

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"============HANDLE OPEN URL");
    ViewController *v =(ViewController *) vc;
    return [[v facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```