# IOS5 Facebook integration - fbDidLogin is not called 

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

I've been spending days on doing a simple Facebook post through an app. I used this [tutorial](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-through.html) and found out that fbDidLogin is not called. As I've been looking for solutions, I've found out that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called) is a way to make the fbDidLogin be called.

Enlighten me as to what I may be missing out.

Attached here is the essential methods for FB integration in my `app delegate`.

App delegate.m

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize wallSnapVC = _wallSnapVC;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.wallSnapVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wallSnapViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.wallSnapVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [[_wallSnapVC facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [[_wallSnapVC facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: There is api called Graph API for facebook integration are using this API ?

Comment: I had an issue with the connectivity when I try to implement it: did you check if you set up the appId correctly within the info.plist? make sure it is the item 0 of URLSchemes which is item 0 of URLTypes. Is the openURL method called correctly?

Comment: @tiguero yes, I've done that already bro

Comment: @SALMAN I know that, have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: are you done with the process of getting API key and Secret key ? just asking ?

Comment: @Grauzten you can use the below sample application which I have posted as an answer as it is very easy to use and integrate :)  Thanks

Comment: Have you called Facebook Delegate method in your appDelegate class?